# LAS files - Python

Tags: python, las, log-ascii-standard

I'm pretty sure this is a very menial question about LAS files, but I wasn't entirely sure how to google this. For context, I'm trying to create a plot given the information in a LAS file.

```
import lasio as ls
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

well = ls.read(r'1051325649.las')
df = well.df() 

fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

#Set up the plot axes
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,3), (0,0), rowspan=1, colspan = 1) 
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1,3), (0,1), rowspan=1, colspan = 1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((1,3), (0,2), rowspan=1, colspan = 1)

ax1.plot("GR", "DEPT", data = df, color = "green") # Call the data from the well dataframe
ax1.set_title("Gamma") # Assign a track title
ax1.set_xlim(0, 200) # Change the limits for the curve being plotted
ax1.set_ylim(400, 1000) # Set the depth range
ax1.grid() # Display the grid
```

The LAS file pretty much looks like this where I want to create a plot where the far left column "DEPT" should be the X-axis. However, the "DEPT" or depth column isn't able to be made into a format to allow for me to plot it. **Note: there is a GR column on the right not in this picture, so don't worry. Any tips would help greatly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer:

`plt.plot` expects that both `"GR"` and `"DEPT"` are columns in `df`, however the latter (`DEPT`) is not a column, it is the index. You can solve it by converting the index in `df` to a column:

```
df2 = df.reset_index()
ax1.plot("GR", "DEPT", data = df2, color = "green")
```

Answer (score 1):

When reading `.las` files using `lasio` library and converting them to `pandas` dataframe, it automatically sets `DEPT` as the index for the dataframe.

There are two solutions for this problem:

1. Use the data as-is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import lasio

well = lasio.read('filename.las')
well_df = well.df()

plt.plot(well_df.GR, well_df.index)
```

And `well_df.index` will be the `DEPT` values.

2. Reset the index and use `DEPT` as a column

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import lasio

well = lasio.read('filename.las')
well_df = well.df()

well_df = well_df.reset_index()

plt.plot(well_df.GR, well_df.DEPT)
```