# How do i convert a las file into a txt (or csv) file in python?

Tags: python, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, txt, las

As the title suggested, how can i convert a .las file in a .txt or .csv file? Does laspy library do that?

Someone suggested to use pdal ([.LAS into a .CSV file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042901/las-into-a-csv-file-using-python)) but it is not clear how to do that

Comment: Can u post how data looks inside the `.Las` file? or upload your sample .Las to Gdrive or drop box post link here.

Comment: For privacy, I cannot share data here. 
What details are you interested in? There are points with x,y,z, and classification information

Comment: Try modifying the data & change data with dummy values. With out sample data it's not possible to shape & convert files...

Comment: If you don;t post the sample data. Question will be closed again

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7894767fcbb75ce1ea200b3bc65f735020221115135626/f8167b

Comment: Take a look at [LAS files - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66175870/las-files-python) for an approach

Answer (score 0):

Solved in this way:

```
inFile = laspy.file.File(inputFile, mode='r')
test = np.vstack((inFile.x, inFile.y, inFile.z, inFile.raw_classification)).transpose()

with open(outFolder+"\\test.txt", mode='w') as f:
for i in range(len(test)):
    f.write("%f    "%float(test[i][0].item()))
    f.write("%f    "%float(test[i][1].item()))
    f.write("%f    "%float(test[i][2].item()))
    f.write("%d    \n"%int(test[i][3].item()))
```